# не запускается artisan serve в laradock контейнере workspace

Tags: laravel, docker, laradock

есть проект на laravel. использую окружение laradock для запуска проекта. для запуска делаю 
`docker-compose up -d workspace mysql php-fpm` 
`docker-compose exec workspace bash` 
`cd ПАПКА_ПРОЕКТА` 
`php artisan serve` 
но вот проблема, что после запуска последней команды (`serve`) в консоли выводится 
`Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000` и так и стоит. сервер не запускается.

Версия php в workspace (`php -v`):

> PHP 7.3.27-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Feb  7 2021
> 11:57:25) ( NTS )

Дистрибутив в workspace (`neofetch`):

> Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS x86_64 
> Host: Virtual Machine Hyper-V UEFI Release v4.0

Да и вообще очень странно себя ведет у меня laradock. к примеру есть еще такое что `npm run dev` **очень** медленно работает и `npm run watch` так же медленно собирает но плюс еще не делает `watch` т.е. при изменении в файлах не обновляется

nodejs (`node -v`):

> 7.5.3

npm (`npm -v`):

> v15.8.0

Что я пробовал делать:

- Переустанавливал Docker, Laradock, WSL2
- Переключал Docker с WSL2 на Hyper-V и наоборот
- Use the WSL2 based engine в Docker
- Clean / Purge data в Docker
- apt update && apt upgrade в workspace

Даже не знаю в чем может быть проблема

Вот некоторые конфиги проекта:
**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.0-beta.17",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue": "^3.0.5",
        "vue-loader": "^16.1.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.5",
        "swiper": "^6.4.11"
    }
}
```

Laravel (`php artisan --version`):

> Laravel Framework 8.26.1

[docker-compose.yml](https://pastebin.com/tvhGdH8h) laradock

[.env](https://pastebin.com/85Snbk8S) laradock

`time npm run dev`

> real    1m1.804s 
> user    0m16.883s 
> sys     0m6.296s

*p.s. возможет быть надо что то поменять в `php.ini` поскольку мне удалось воспроизвести эту проблему вне workspace когда раскомментировал `php.ini-development` который был у меня в windows 10*

Comment: `и так и стоит. сервер не запускается.` почему вы считаете что сервер не запущен? он висит на 8000 порту, который доступен внутри контейнера, но скорее всего вы наружу его не открывали. `docker-compose up -d workspace mysql php-fpm` - настройте nginx и добавьте его в запуск. тогда не нужны эти танцы с `serve`. ` при изменении в файлах не обновляется` - а файл действительно поменялся? думаю, вы меняете его на хост машине, файловая система не подключена как volume, и естественно внутри контейнера никаких изменений нет. покажите docker-compose.yml

Comment: `WSL2` - как я понял, у вас винда, и работает медленно по причине тормознутости WSL2. напишите выхлоп `time npm run prod` в вопросе, чтобы понять насколько это вообще долго. у вас же JS еще нет как такового, только тот, идет из коробки?

Comment: @TotalPusher обновил вопрос

Comment: `${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}` - эту часть вы настроили? почему nginx не запускаете? на странице проекта рекомендует запускать именно так. а если workspace - то порт пробросили? покажите .env файл

Comment: `time npm run dev` - действительно долго, у меня 30 сек на SSD. Я грешу на WSL2 или у вас HDD или вообще старый комп, других идей у меня нет. `watch` медленно работает скорее всего по той же причине. В Linux есть механизм слежения за файлами inotify, а есть ли он WSL2, я не могу сказать, и тогда npm начинает использовать "legacy mode", который тормозит.

Comment: @TotalPusher добавил .env. поднял nginx. теперь проблема со скоростью сборки остается

Comment: Я думаю, проблема в WSL2. Я работаю на Linux, поэтому такая проблема мне не известна. Но вот [тут](https://dev.to/kleeut/why-is-wsl2-so-slow-4n3i) как раз пишут про это. И в комментах советуют использовать WSL1. Вы все починили и все работает?

Comment: @TotalPusher да. и если вы перенесете свои рекомендации и решения в ответ. вопрос был бы закрыт

Comment: @TotalPusher дело действительно в WSL2 на оф странице microsoft wsl говорится о том что Performance across OS file systems медленный у wsl2. медленне чем wsl1. но как переключить docker на wsl1 непонято. советуют кинуть проект в фс wsl2(этак контейнера) для повышения скорости. и что теперь? проект кидать в контейнер?

Comment: Не могу подсказать. Но можно открыть еще один вопрос на SO :) Как вариант, использовать виртуальную машину. У Лары есть официальный проект [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead), который по сути Vagrant + ВМ. Это не докер. Но на ВМ также можно поднять ларадок, если вам так удобно. И еще один вариант - это начать использовать Linux.

Comment: @TotalPusher оставил новый вопрос. его решение позволит обойти проблему скорости https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1242830/319165

Answer (score 0, accepted):

действительно нет особо смысла использовать `artisan serve`. лучше поднять `nginx` и использовать его. как сделать: 
`docker-compose up -d nginx` 
`docker-compose exec nginx bash` 
`apk add nano && nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` 
в этом файле ищете подобное

```
...
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf;
open_file_cache off; # Disabled for issue 619
charset UTF-8;
...
```

и добавляете такую строку

```
include /var/www/*/*.nginx;
```

**!!!** только если вы не меняли пути в `.env` laradock. если меняли вместо `/var/www/` укажите свой путь до папки проектов.

затем в корень проекта (у меня laravel проект). добавляете nginx файл конфигурации. у меня содержимое файла такое:
**config.nginx**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    # не забудьте добавить домен в hosts в виндовс (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc).
    # а то можете как я просидеть пол часа думая что же не так
    server_name my_laravel_project.localhost;
    

    access_log /var/www/my_laravel_project/storage/logs/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /var/www/my_laravel_project/storage/logs/nginx_error.log;

    root /var/www/my_laravel_project/public;
    index index.php;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    charset utf-8;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    # serve static files directly
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    if (!-d $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # enforce NO www
    if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*))
    {
        set $host_without_www $1;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www/$1 permanent;
    }

    # unless the request is for a valid file (image, js, css, etc.), send to bootstrap
    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
        break;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream; # may also be: 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

теперь выходим из контейнера и делаем 
`docker-compose restart` 
и теперь по идее наш проект открыт по адресу my_laravel_project.localhost

*p.s если в каком-то из описанных мною шагов есть ошибка. оставьте комментарий или правьте вопрос*

*p.s. решение о скорости wsl2 смотрите в ответе [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1242830/319165)*