# remote container folder sharing на phpstorm или как подключиться к контейнеру из phpstorm или как сделать container - wsl - phpstorm

Tags: docker, wsl2

у меня есть docker контейнер в котором лежит проект. я могу подключиться к фс контейнера и изменять проект используя [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) и его расширения [Remote - WSL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) и [Remote - Containers](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/07/01/containers-wsl#_open-vs-code-in-wsl-2). т.е. я делаю как показано на оф странице докера о [remote wsl](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/07/01/containers-wsl#_open-vs-code-in-wsl-2). и хотел так же подключиться через phpstorm, подобного расширения я не нашел в маркетплейсе и подумал сделать с созданием символической ссылки `ИЗ_WSL2 -> В_WINDOWS` но у меня в WSL нет папки проекта и не знаю как подключить папку с проектом из контейнера в WSL. ну тут возникает два выхода,

1. подключиться из phpstorm напрямую к фс докер контейнера `PhpStorm -> DOCKER_CONTAINER` (как я это делаю с VS Code)
2. каким то образом подключить директорию из докер контейнера в WSL (у меня Ubuntu-20.04 LTS) и открыть проект из него. (есть способ открыть проект из wsl в phpstorm. с той же символ-ой ссылкой) `DOCKER_CONTAINER -> WSL2 -> PhpStorm`

я гуглил и не нашел ответа ни на первый, ни на второй вопрос. может кто сталкивался с подобным с знает что делать?

p.s. из этих двух вариантов предпочтительнее второй. поскольку к wsl можно получить доступ из проводника (`\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04`) и работа с ним была бы удобнее

Comment: а почему для вас не подходит использование монтирования volume в docker? у вас есть папка с проектом в windows, примонтировали его к контейнеру и открыли в ide, все изменения будут отображаться в контейнере

Comment: @ExplodingKitten потому что wsl2 имеет проблемы Performance across OS file systems. и такие команды как `npm run dev` выполняются очень медленно. я уже оставлял вопрос по этой теме https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1242390/319165 микромягкие сами рекомендуют переместить файлы во внутрь wsl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

получилось сделать такой вариант. вместо того чтобы использовать `laradock` в windows его можно установить в самом wsl (у меня ubuntu-20.04 LTS). возможность docker c `17.` версии [WSL intergration](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/) позволит вам использовать в взаимодействии ваш wsl и docker. естественно вам не будут доступны директории из контейнеров. но вам будут доступно управление docker (docker-desktop и docker-desktop-data). таким образом развернув `laradock` в wsl можно избежать [описанной проблемы скорости](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions) между windows и wsl. (ну поскольку wsl у вас скорее всего будет linux и получается `linux(wsl) -> docker`)
а поскольку доступ к wsl можно получить из виндовс. то проект открыть в phpstorm не составит труда (та же символ-ая ссылка). как сделать:
**требования:**

1. [Включите Hyper-V](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v)
2. [Установите \ Обновите WSL в вашей Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)
3. Установите сам Docker в Windows и включите [Use WSL2 engine](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/#install) (кажется по умолчанию включена)
4. Установите какой-нибудь дистрибутив из Windows Store. (к примеру [Ubuntu-20.04](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-2004-lts/9n6svws3rx71?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)) 
   4.1 при первом запуске дистрибутива вам нужно будет его настроить (ввести root пароль и юзернейм)

**чо куда тыкать:**

6. В настройках Docker `Resources -> WSL INTEGRATION` включите ваш дистрибутив
7. В cmd или powershell введите команду `wsl` чтобы попасть в дистрибутив (но легче всего использовать [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) туда после установки сразу добавляется дистрибутив)
8. Перейдите в `~/home/USER_NAME/projects` (не обязательно этот путь, главное чтобы это не была директория вашей Windows системы)
9. По стандарту сделайте `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
10. Установите git. и склонируйте `laradock` затем get started (ну типа .`env` сделать).
11. Помните тык 6? вам доступен docker внутри вашего wsl. поэтому смело `docker-compose up -d ...`
12. наконец клонируете ваш проект так же в wsl (**важно** опять же использовать только директории wsl) и создайте символ-ую ссылку для phpstorm. в фс wsl можно зайти написав в проводнике путь `\\wsl$\ИМЯ_ДИСТРИБУТИВА\`. посмотреть имя дистрибутива можно выполнив команду `wsl -l`